# text renders over solid rect, but doesnt render over gradient

Tags: java, android

I'm new to Android development, and trying to render a button to a Canvas object in an onDraw method, basically text over a backfield.  It's a good way to get my feet wet with some of the rendering commands.

I am able to fill a solid rectangle and then draw centered text over it, but when I try to fill a gradient rectangle, and then draw text over it, the text doesn't draw.

Code is below, cobbled together from various examples.  Basically:

- DO_PAINT=0, DO_GRADIENT=0 -> text renders
- DO_PAINT=1, DO_GRADIENT=0 -> solid rectangle with text on top
- DO_PAINT=0, DO_GRADIENT=1 -> gradient rectangle (no text) !!!

So something about my gradient drawing interferes with my text rendering.  I'm guessing that I'm leaving something in a bad state in the Paint object, but I'm not sure what property that would be...

Any insight or thoughts are greatly appreciated...

```
import android.graphics.LinearGradient;
import android.graphics.Paint;
import android.graphics.Rect;
import android.graphics.Shader;
import android.graphics.Typeface;
import android.view.View;
import android.graphics.Paint;
import android.content.Context;
import android.graphics.Color;
import android.graphics.Canvas;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.MotionEvent;
import android.app.Activity;

public class cMyView extends View
{
    public cMyView(Context context, Activity owner_activity)
    {
        super(context);
    }

    final Paint m_paint = new Paint();
    public String m_Text = "Button";
    private final Rect textBounds = new Rect(); 
    public Typeface m_TypeFace = Typeface.create("Arial",Typeface.NORMAL);
    public int m_TextColor = Color.argb(255,0,0,0);
    public int m_TextSize = 32;

    @Override
    protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {

        Rect m_Bounds = new Rect(100,100,500,200);
        boolean DO_PAINT = false;
        boolean DO_GRADIENT = true;


    if ( DO_PAINT) {
        m_paint.setStyle(Paint.Style.FILL);
        m_paint.setColor(Color.GREEN);
        canvas.drawRect(m_Bounds, m_paint);
    }

    if (DO_GRADIENT) {
        m_paint.setShader(new LinearGradient(0, m_Bounds.top, 0, m_Bounds.bottom, Color.BLACK, Color.WHITE, Shader.TileMode.MIRROR));
        canvas.drawRect(m_Bounds.left, m_Bounds.top, m_Bounds.right, m_Bounds.bottom, m_paint);
    }

    m_paint.setColor(m_TextColor);
    m_paint.setTextSize(m_TextSize);
    m_paint.setTypeface(m_TypeFace);

    m_paint.getTextBounds(m_Text, 0, m_Text.length(), textBounds);

    double x = m_Bounds.left + m_Bounds.width()/2  - textBounds.exactCenterX();
    double y = m_Bounds.top  + m_Bounds.height()/2 - textBounds.exactCenterY();

    canvas.drawText(m_Text, (float) x, (float) y, m_paint);

}
```

}

Comment: #define is not Java's syntax. I'm sorry for possibly annoying question, but are you sure the code is even compiled?

Comment: Oops, sorry... I boiled it down a bit and added the #define constants just to show what worked and didn't.  That's all I added.  In actuality I commented and uncommented those sections.

Comment: Edited to clarify.  My bad.

Comment: Why not use use an if? Then its immediately obvious...

Comment: Chris, I feel you will get more help if you post an entire class, incl. text color, typeface, etc. So other users, who would like to help you, may just paste the code into a new project

Comment: Entire class provided.  In its current state it will draw a gradient rectangle but will NOT draw the text after/over it, I'm  not sure why.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just add an another Paint for text, this is worked for me, and I found the reason, if you comment 2-nd row in DO_GRADIENT case (in your code), then will see that text is gradient, it mean that it draw, but have same gradient as background have, and becomes invisible.

```
public class CustomView extends View {
public CustomView(Context context) {
    super(context);
}

public CustomView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
    super(context, attrs);
}

public CustomView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyleAttr) {
    super(context, attrs, defStyleAttr);
}

final Paint m_paint = new Paint();
public String m_Text = "Button";
private final Rect textBounds = new Rect();
public Typeface m_TypeFace = Typeface.create("Arial",Typeface.NORMAL);
public int m_TextColor = Color.argb(255, 0, 0, 0);
public int m_TextSize = 32;
private final Paint textPaint = new Paint();

@Override
protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {

    Rect m_Bounds = new Rect(100,100,500,200);
    boolean DO_PAINT = true;
    boolean DO_GRADIENT = true;


    if ( DO_PAINT) {
        m_paint.setStyle(Paint.Style.FILL);
        m_paint.setColor(Color.GREEN);
        canvas.drawRect(m_Bounds, m_paint);
    }

    if (DO_GRADIENT) {
        m_paint.setShader(new LinearGradient(0, m_Bounds.top, 0, m_Bounds.bottom, Color.BLACK, Color.WHITE, Shader.TileMode.MIRROR));
        canvas.drawRect(m_Bounds.left, m_Bounds.top, m_Bounds.right, m_Bounds.bottom, m_paint);
    }

    m_paint.setColor(m_TextColor);
    m_paint.setTextSize(m_TextSize);
    m_paint.setTypeface(m_TypeFace);

    m_paint.getTextBounds(m_Text, 0, m_Text.length(), textBounds);

    double x = m_Bounds.left + m_Bounds.width()/2  - textBounds.exactCenterX();
    double y = m_Bounds.top  + m_Bounds.height()/2 - textBounds.exactCenterY();

    textPaint.setColor(m_TextColor);
    textPaint.setTextSize(m_TextSize);
    textPaint.setTypeface(m_TypeFace);
    canvas.drawText(m_Text, (float) x, (float) y, textPaint);

}
```

[image: Screenshot]

Comment: Thanks!!  What is the right thing to do in terms of number of paint objects, by the way?  Are they expensive to the system?  If I'm doing a lot of rendering, can I create 100, configure each once/separately, and then use each to do the separate parts of the rendering?

Comment: I used a lot of paint objects in my map program, it's no heavy, only thing is that you don't create them inside the onDraw method, because onDraw can call even 60 times per second, but if you pre-allocate those objects before onDraw, for example inside the constructor, rendering will be faster